# Which is the correct way to connect the gate and pull down resistors?

Tags: mosfet, switching, gate-driving

There are two forms of connecting this two resistors
[image: Connection "X"]

[image: Connection "Z"]

If in both cases Rg=1k and Rpd=10k which connection is better?
I mean, i know that in the first connection there is a voltage divider so Vin!=Vgs and in the second connection Vin=Vgs.

In the first connection there is a Rt=11k and in the second it s a Rt=10k, so yeah the first one is a little bit more efficient

Now, imaging the driver is not an MCU and it is a mechanical switch, the first connection discharges a little bit faster than the second.

But the second one is more efficient in terms that there are no voltage divider and Vin=Vgs

I know if Rpd=100k in the first connection we also can say that Vgs= =.99Vin.

So which is the best connection?

I think that for "normal switching" like turning on/off an AC motor once per hour the second one is better, but for fast switching applications or "hard" PWM the first one is better because it reduces a little bit the switching frequencies; is that ok?

Or is it there something else to consider (a.k.a ringing) that determines which is better?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't turn on and off an AC motor with that circuit and Rg is usually a few tens of ohms maximum so, does it really make much difference?

Comment: As Andy states the series gate resistor is usually very low or even non-existent so it doesn't matter much. The only reason there is a gate resistor at all is usually to suppress ringing and for that purpose a few ohms is adequate (eg 22 ohms).

Comment: Thanks andy and kevin, but what about if my mosfet driver is an arduino? i need a more larger resistor to limit the maximu current of an output pin isnt it? because with 22 ohms and 5V, my current will be 227mA, am i missing something?

Comment: @CblueX Mosfets are not BJTs. The base Gate does draw no static current. The charge required to switch a FET are extremly low. Think of pico-coulombs. Therefore, a current limit is not necessary - the GPIOs internal IMPEDANCE (not resistance) will limit it enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, the answer "what is correct" depends on the circumstances.

If you need 'equal' switch on/off times you would prefer (b) as the GPIO can be seen as 'GND' too. The pulldown is just during RESET - when the GPIO is High-Z.

If you want fast switch on/off times you also use (b) - your voltage divider also slows the switch on edge.

If you need fast switch off times in case GPIO goes HIGH-Z you use (a) as the Gate-GND resistance is smaller.

**And the list goes on ...**

If you are doing a simple switch ... just don't care. Both ways work, both have their pro's and con's - you don't care.

In case you need a "pro" zou will have to take the "con".

**In short**

- If you don't need to know: don't care
- If you need to know: simulate

Comment: Thanks man , i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Picture (b) since in picture (a) you are creating a voltage divider and the voltage at the gate of the mosfet wont be the same as the voltage of the output pin.However in picture(b) you will have a bigger pulldown transition time.

Comment: Thank u miss mulan